# How to show modal / panel in overlay HTML - CSS

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show this panel or modal in html /  css but i cant show it because i have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and when i remove that link the modal will show but when it is there the modal does not show.

P.S I cannot remove that link because all of my design will be removed or will not be visible so how can i show that modal without removing that link here is my css

`style`

```
      <style type="text/css">

body {
    /* general styles */
    padding: 30px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

}

/* overlay styles, all needed */
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 10;
}

/* just some content with arbitrary styles for explanation purposes */
.modal {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    background-color: #f1c40f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 11; /* 1px higher than the overlay layer */
}

.content {
    margin: 30px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Federo', sans-serif;
}
  </style>
```

my `div`

```
     <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="modal" id="modal"><?php echo $row['id']; ?> <?php echo $row['additional_info']; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't show the dialog because the `modal` class is also used by Bootstrap.

If you change the line `<div class="modal" id="modal">` to `<div class="mymodal" id="modal">` you will see that it now appears. Be sure to also update your class name in your css as well.